# How to load RemoteMessage total data in FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to load FCM notification total Json data in Android using below method, but it's not printing entire data - it is just printing below data. How can I load through out data which coming from server?

### Server payload

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("to", deviceToken.trim());
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("Key-1", Message);
    data.put("Key-2", Message1);
    json.put("data", data);

    JSONObject info = new JSONObject();
    info.put("title", "EZBitex Exchange"); 
    info.put("body", "EZBitex Exchange");
    info.put("message", "hello user");
    json.put("notification", info);

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(json.toString());
    wr.flush();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
    String output;
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
    System.out.println("GCM Notification is sent successfully");
    result = "succcess";
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    result = "failure";
}
return result;
```

### Android

```
public class FirebaseMessagingservice extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        System.out.println("NEW_TOKEN is---->"+s);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
        System.out.println("JSON_OBJECT is---->"+object.toString());
    }
}
```

### printing data

```
JSON_OBJECT is---->{"Key-1":"Hello dude","Key-2":"welcome to Ezbitex exchange"}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `remoteMessage.getData()` fetch data payload. same `remoteMessage.getNotification()` fetch notification payload

I hope you are looking for this code for getting notification object.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){

        Log.d(TAG, "Notification object:" + remoteMessage.getNotification());
        //show notification in tray here - if required

        Log.d(TAG, "Notification body:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());//will get "EZBitex Exchange"
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification title:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());//will get "EZBitex Exchange"

    }
}
```